# How to make XMLUnit work in eclipse?

Tags: junit, xmlunit

I have the JUnit (junit-4.11.jar) installed in eclipse as you can see in the screenshot below but I have no idea how to make XMLUnit work. Can somone please help?

[image]

As you can see I've downloaded the .zip (xmlunit-0.4.zip) from XMLUnit website and loaded it in the path in Eclipse, but still, Eclipse do not recognize the XMLTestCase extension as you can see below.

Any help will be very helpful.

Comment: use the jar instead of the zip

Comment: There is no .jar in the sourceforge source. Tust the .zip one.

Comment: http://www.findjar.com/jar/xmlunit/xmlunit/1.3/xmlunit-1.3.jar.html

Answer (score 1):

You've download XMLUnit for .NET.

There is a download for Java at sourceforge (1.6 is the current version) and it is also available via Maven Central